# Azure AD B2C portal will not save my redirect uri

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

The Azure AD B2C - App Registrations (both current and preview) will not save my non localhost address. i.e. if I add a redirect Uri as https://localhost:44734, and save it works fine. If I add a uri as https://mysite.azurewebsites.net it will not save. The details here is slightly different depending on the part of the portal you are in.

If you are using the "App Registrations (Preview)" version, you see a notification in the top right saying "Update application Authentication". This just stays there and never finishes.

if you are using the current Applications blade you get an error stating "Application Update Error" "Cannot update Application: One of the properties provided for the application 'XXXXX' has invalid value. Please read this article (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=847767) for more details.". This seems to be the case for any URL except localhost.

Also manually editing the manifest is also giving the error.

You should be able to add both localhost, and any valid url in that screen. Which seems to work on a new Application, but not an existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not reproduce your issue on my side. I think you can create a new application to resolve this issue.

Also, you can try to delete all the reply urls and then add it again.

Comment: Ok, deleting all the reply urls seems to have done the trick. It seems like at some point the .b2clogin.com.... url was automatically added. After removing that I was able to add my own. Thanks for the reply.